# Select and Print 2 Certain Seperate Rows from mysql Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have small script that JOIN 2 rows from 2 seperate tables and print them together.

However, i want to pull and print those 2 seperated rows from the 2 seperate tables one-by-one (to css design each row results separately) instead of JOIN

The sql JOIN process:

```
SELECT  b.topic, a.message,  a.threadID 
FROM wbb1_post a
JOIN wbb1_thread b ON b.threadID = a.threadID
```

The whole script **index3.php**:

```
<?php
//header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";
$id =(int)$_GET['id'];
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");


$sql = "SELECT  b.topic, a.message,  a.threadID 
FROM wbb1_post a
JOIN wbb1_thread b ON b.threadID = a.threadID 
 WHERE a.threadID = $id";
//print_r
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $obj[] = $row;
    }
} else {

}
$conn->close();
?>
```

The **test1.php** page code:

```
<div>
<?php
$_GET['id'] = 4;
include 'index3.php'  ;?>
</div>
```

To print 2 row results seperatly i thought about something like that:

**index3.php** code:

```
$sql = "SELECT  a.message,  a.threadID 
FROM wbb1_post a
 WHERE a.threadID = $id";

$sql2 = "SELECT  b.topic, b.threadID
FROM wbb1_thread b 
WHERE b.threadID = $sub";

//print_r
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$result = $conn->query($sql2);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $obj[] = $row;
    }
} else {

}
$conn->close();
?>
```

**test1.php** code:

```
<div>
<?php
$_GET['sub'] = 4;
include 'index3.php'  ;?>
</div>
<br><br>
<div>
<?php
$_GET['id'] = 4;  
include 'index3.php' ;?>
</div>
```

But all i get is the subject line ['id'] twice.

Answer (score 0):

Use UNION

```
$sql = "SELECT a.message AS Val,  a.threadID 
FROM wbb1_post a WHERE a.threadID = $id
UNION ALL 
SELECT b.topic AS Val,  b.threadID 
FROM wbb1_post a WHERE b.threadID = $id";
```

Comment: I want to design the $id and the $sub seperatly via div containers